# how to setup an ajax-request for ember-data with hasMany-relationship correctly?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

after i full day of trying i give up. for a very basic application in ember.js i tried to setup an ajax request to the server that answers with a proper reply. the problem is not to get the model data (custom_route) from the server showing up in an array controller's template. but what i couldn't manage to fetch is the data of the related model (station).
The both models are definded as followed:

```
App.CustomRoute = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string'),
  stations: DS.hasMany(App.Station)
});

App.Station = DS.Model.extend({
        name: attr('string'),
        description: attr('string'),
        stations: DS.hasMany(App.Station)
    });
```

Using the FixtureAdapter everything works perfectly fine after adding {async: true} as parameter to both methods. But with the default RESTful adapter the only thing i get displayed is the data from the custom_route model. That leads me to my question: How has the ajax reply to look like that the adapter fetches both the data from both models.
On the net I couldnt find an example of how a reply to a findAll() request that resolves a model and its related models. Everything I found only examplifies how the reply should look like (including sideload) if a request for a single module is fired
I had tried

```
{
   "custom_routes": [
      {
         "custom_route": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Route 1",
            "description": "Description 1",
            "station_ids": [
               1,
               2,
               3
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "stations": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Station 1",
         "description": "Description 1",
      }
   ]
}
```

but that didn't work. But if the keyname "custom_route" for a single represtentation of the model is left of the "custom_routes" entries are displayed. 
Hopefully there is a work around for that problem and hopefully my english was good enough to describe the issue. I am neither an native speaker nor a long-time web developer. But looking forward to improve both :)

Comment: I knew it ... after posting my question I found that solution. the correct reply has to look as following:
`{
   "custom_routes": [
       {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Route 1",
            "description": "Description 1",
            "stations": [
               1,
               2,
               3
            ]
         }
   ],
   "stations": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Station 1",
         "description": "Description 1",
      }
   ]
}`
Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember Data made a breaking change between RC 13 and 1.0, see the transition

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

for additional breaking changes.

Comment: thanks. that clarifies a lot. there are just way too many blog posts around which don't make explicitly clear which ember-data they relate to and the ember guide isn't very descriptive yet when it comes to ember data (which isn't really surprising due to the fact that ember data is beta and wip).

Comment: say i have the models custom_route and user. to get the data for the routes that belong to the user ajax requests that look like "/users/:user_id/routes" have to be send to the server. now .. how do i get ember-data to send these get requests? 

When i setup the specific route related to this request like this:

 `App.UserCustomRoutesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
         model: function() {
       
             return this.store.find('user_custom_route');      });`

... the request is just '/user_custom_route'

Comment: Schuppo would you mind creating a new question so we can keep the answers separate and help future people who search for a similar problem?

Comment: That and it's really hard to give good answers in the comments ;)